# remove default visibilty icon from outlineinput material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i want to remove  default visibilty icon from outlineinput material ui. when input type is password there is a default visibilty icon showing. i want to remove it. i am using inputAdorment for custom visibilty icon.

Here is my code..

```
 <FormControl variant="outlined">
                          <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password">
                            What’s your current password?
                          </InputLabel>
                          <OutlinedInput
                            id="outlined-adornment-password"
                            type={showCurrentPsw ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            value={currentPassword}
                            name="currentpsw"
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                              setCurrentPassword(value);
                              value !== '' &&
                                value.trim() !== '' &&
                                setCurrentPswdEmpty(false);
                            }}
                            error={currentPswdEmpty}
                            label="What’s your current password?"
                            required
                            endAdornment={
                              <InputAdornment position="end">
                                <IconButton
                                  aria-label="What’s your current password?"
                                  onClick={() => {
                                    setShowCurrentPsw(!showCurrentPsw);
                                  }}
                                  edge="end"
                                >
                                  {showCurrentPsw ? (
                                    <Visibility />
                                  ) : (
                                    <VisibilityOff />
                                  )}
                                </IconButton>
                              </InputAdornment>
                            }
                          />
                        </FormControl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**it solved by using below css. parentclassname => class name of the parent element. this is a react project.**

```
.parentclassname input[type='password']::-ms-reveal,
.parentclassname input[type='password']::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```js
<OutlinedInput
    // ...
    sx={{
        '& input[type="password"]::-ms-reveal': { display: 'none' },
        '& input[type="password"]::-ms-clear': { display: 'none' },
    }}
/>
```